# "To" or without "to"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality

Is first one incorrect? If so, then and why there should be to?
And what respond would be?

> Where did you disappear?

> Where did you disappear to?

Comment: duplicate of an answer from me: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/91010/is-to-always-necessary/227913#227913

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Where did he disappear?

Answer: He disappeared in the woods.

- Where did you disappear to? [meaning: where did you go? I didn't see you]

Answer: I went out jogging

**disappear to** is used in colloquial spoken language to mean: go, when it seems that a person has "disappeared". Indeed, they have disappeared from the view of the speaker.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the second form violates the English grammar rule that prohibits ending a sentence with a preposition, and the correct form would be "To where did  you disappear?"